# ListView -- start out scrolled to particular position

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, scroll

If I have an *existing* ListView, I know can scroll it to a position with calls like

```
smoothScrollToPosition(position)
```

or

```
scrollListBy(pixels)
```

But what about a new listview that I am creating?  I want it to start out scrolled to a certain position, without any movement when it first appears.  How can I do that?

An important part of this is presumably making the scroll call at the correct time.  But I'm not sure what the "correct time" is.

Comment: What is wrong with setting the scroll position at the end of onCreate()? The ListView won't be rendered before onCreate() finishes running.

Comment: I currently have it at the end of OnResume() for my Fragment.  But the ListView still appears scrolled to the top.